# Flutter - Google and Facebook sign in button crashes in Google Play store

Tags: flutter, google-play

So I am building a test project where I will implement Google and Facebook sign in. It works fine on debug mode with emulator and USB debugger. However, after releasing it to Google Playstore, it crashes to home screen. I'm also using Firebase in this project.

Answer (score 0):

Test your application in release mode (only in physical device):

```
flutter run --release
```

But first, you have to put a lot of `print()`, because when you run your application in this mode, debug information is removed and debugging is disabled ([Flutter's build modes](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/build-modes)).

For example, put `print()` before logging in, when pressing the button, when returning and at the end of the process. In this way, you constantly monitor what is happening.

Another option is to encapsulate the function in charge of executing the login with a `try/catch` and print the error in the catch.